# Unable to fire notification from content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am unable to fire a notification from my Chrome extension. I am aware that we cannot fire it directly from a content script, which is the reason I have the notification code in the *background.js* file. But, that still isn't working. I need your help in figuring out how to display notifications from a Chrome extension.

**Content Script:**

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "xdsfds",
  "author": "Miraj",
  "background": {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"],
    "persistent" : false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://google.com/*","file:///*/Desktop/extensionPage.html"],
       "js": ["/js/lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
              "/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js",
              "/js/lib/angular.min.js",
              "/js/lib/idbstore.js",
              "/js/contentScript.js",
              "/js/angJs/main.js",
              "/js/angJs/communiqueService.js",
              "/js/angJs/commTrackerDir.js"],
         "css": ["/css/sforce.css",
               "/css/main.css"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "/templates/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
     "cookies",
     "unlimitedStorage",
   "notifications"
  ]
}
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert('i am listening'); //this is getting invoked

        var opt = {
            type: "basic",
            title: "Primary Title",
            message: "Primary message to display",
            iconUrl: '/images/notification.png'
        };
        chrome.notifications.create(new Date().getTime(), opt, function(rs){
            alert(rs);
        });

        sendResponse({returnMsg: "All good!"}); // optional response
    });
```

**ContentScript.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({msg: "Sup?"}, function(response) {
    // optional callback - gets response
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Have you verified that your notification fires when outside the `extension.onMessage` listener? What do you see in the extension's background page console?

Comment: Why are you using `chrome.extension.onMessage`/`sendMessage`?  I would expect you to use [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage).

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for `chrome.notifications.create`should be a string. `new Date().getTime()` returns an integer. You could use `""+new Date().getTime()` to convert it to a string.